# MVC 3.0 Protect form content from modification using firebug/developer tools

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form (say employee details modification form) where the unique id (say emp id) is kept in a hidden form field and same is available in the model when the form is posted back.

That id will be used for database update.

But user can modify the same using firebug/developer tools. How can we protect it?

Comment: Take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312779/prevent-hidden-input-from-being-altered

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is the right solution, but you can store the `id` in `session variable` and
when you are posting back the form, you can retrieve it from the `session` and further process it to save in database...